# Поисковик на python3 DB

Tags: python, search

Я делаю поисковик по базе данных.
Например: ['книга', 'ручка', 'рука', 'нож']/
Нужно сделать так, чтобы если пользователь ввел: 'кига', ему выдало слово 'книга'.
Если пользователь ввел слово 'ру', ему выдало 'ручка','рука '.
Посоветуйте библиотеку, или же принцип работы.

Comment: Здесь за вас ничего делать не будут. Пытайтесь сделать что-то сами, показывайте что сделали и что не получается и вам помогут

Comment: Я понимаю, я неправильно выразился!
За это извиняюсь 
Мне хотелось узнать библиотеку или принцип работы.

Comment: https://ru.wikibooks.org/wiki/SQLAlchemy

Answer (score 1):

Можно всё это в цикл, и на условие if, что если в массиве данный элемент содаржит введёный то `print()` если нет то пропустить.